# iOS Facebook, Logout current FB user, then login as different FB user

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

After reading near misses on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068205/calling-logout-function-of-facebook-ios-sdk-is-not-clearing-user-credentials), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649450/ios-facebook-connect-logout-not-deleting-login-details), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999536/ios-facebook-logout-and-clear-user-tokens) and others, my app is still not clearing the previously logged in Facebook user from my device so that I can then login as a different Facebook user.

The very first time I called:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions 
     allowLoginUI:YES 
     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)]
```

Safari opened to a Facebook login page with fields for email and password. After that first time the only page that ever comes up is one saying "You have already authorized [appname]" with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons. There are no other controls to switch user. Even if I delete the app, and clear history and cookies in Safari it still remembers.

My app logs out of Facebook with the following function. The code to delete cookies is included because of information I found in other posts but there are no cookies returned so it actually does nothing.

```
- (void) logoutFaceBook {
    [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        NSString *domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}}}
```