# iOS 13.3 Facebook SDK no longer asking to re-authenticate after logout

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sdk, cocoapods

I haven't updated my app in a few months but now I'm noticing when users logout after signing in with their facebook credentials it is no longer asking for their username and password.

It just says "you previously logged in with Facebook, would you like to continue?".

Logging in still works fine but previously all I had to do was:

```
if (AccessToken.current != nil) {
                let loginManager = LoginManager()
                loginManager.logOut()
}
```

This would remove the access token and force the user to re-enter their credentials.

Has something changed that I'm not aware of? Maybe with the Graph API?

Still on FBSDK 5.8 and Graph API 2.12 and reproducible on a clean simulator with no other apps installed so pretty sure it's not my app. If I erase all content and settings on the simulator it will ask for the credentials the first time I log back in but only then. I have also confirmed the token is no longer present after I logout.
Could it be I need to issue a HTTP DELETE request or something as suggested here:
[ios, Facebook logout AND clear user tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999536/ios-facebook-logout-and-clear-user-tokens)

Couldn't find anything recent referring to this issue so any help is greatly appreciated.